# Django login not getting all the fields

Tags: python, django, forms, authentication, field

i have made a custom user form, and it works to register and everything. but when I try to log in, my user doesnt have any of the attributes from the custom form. let me show you:
models.py

```
class RegisterUser(models.Model):
    user=models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    biography = models.CharField(max_length=1000000,blank=True)
    research_place = models.CharField(max_length=1000000,blank=True)
    studies = models.CharField(max_length=1000000,blank=True)
```

forms.py

```
class RegistrationForm(UserCreationForm):

    fname = forms.CharField(max_length=256, label="", required=True, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control','placeholder': 'First Name','required':True}))
    lname = forms.CharField(max_length=256, label="", required=True, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control','placeholder': 'Last Name','required':True}))
    email = forms.EmailField(max_length=256, label="Email", required=True, widget=forms.EmailInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control','placeholder': 'Email','required':True, 'type':'email'}))
    emailConfirm = forms.EmailField(max_length=256, label="", required=True, widget=forms.EmailInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control','placeholder': 'Confirm Email','required':True, 'type':'email'}))
    password1 = forms.CharField(max_length=256, label="", required=True, widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control','placeholder': 'Password','required':True}))
    password2 =forms.CharField(required=False)

    biography = forms.CharField(label = "Biography",required=False)
    research_place = forms.CharField(label="Research Place",required=False)
    studies = forms.CharField(label="Studies",required=False)

    # class Meta(UserCreationForm.Meta): #extra bit of info
    #   model = user
    #   fields = ('email','emailConfirm','password1','biography','research_place','studies')
    class Meta(): #extra bit of info
        model = User
        fields = ('email','emailConfirm','password1','biography','research_place','studies')
    def clean_username(self):
        username = self.cleaned_data["username"]
        try:
            user.objects.get(username=username)
        except user.DoesNotExist:
            return username
        raise forms.ValidationError(self.error_messages['duplicate_username'])  

    def save(self,commit=True):
        user = super(RegistrationForm,self).save()
        user.first_name=self.cleaned_data['fname']
        user.last_name=self.cleaned_data['lname']
        # user.set_password(self.cleaned_data['password1'])
        user.username = self.cleaned_data['email']
        user.save()

        r_user = RegisterUser(user=user,biography="default1", research_place="default2", studies="default3")
        if commit:
            r_user.save()
            # print ('saving user: %s' % self.user)
        return r_user
```

finally the login view:

```
email=request.POST.get('email','')
password = request.POST.get('password','')
user = authenticate(username=email,password=password)

print(email)
print(password)
print(user)
if user is not None:
    print("notNone")
    login(request,user)
    return HttpResponseRedirect("out")
```

But if i do  {{ user.biography }} in a template, nothing shows up. has_attr also shows that user does not have biography attribute. Does anyone know whats up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `biography` field is on the `RegisterUser` model, not the `User` model. So you have to do `{{ user.registeruser.biography }}` instead of `{{ user.biography }}`.